# Detecting when UINavgiationBar appearance changes from standardAppearance to scrollEdgeAppearance

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uiappearance

How to determine if the Navigation Controllers `UINavigationBar` changes the appearance between

`standardAppearance` <-> `scrollEdgeAppearance`

as the underlaying `UISCrollView` changes it's scroll

There is no property to observe, and i didn't found a callback method